# CSS keyframe animation not working when loaded in Android WebView (IONIC 2)

Tags: android, css, ionic2, css-animations, keyframe

I have an Ionic 2 project and need to present some simple animations to the app. I was doing the animations using keyframes in CSS and all works fine in IOS and in the browser, but not in Android where on some newer devices it's working partially with glitches and on my Nexus 5 it doesn't works at all.

I am using both *-webkit-* and *standard* keyframes to run the animation, so i am a bit lost what i am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
 .throw-object-plastic {
    animation-name: plastic-bin-anim, top-scale;
    animation-duration: 0.8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-name: plastic-bin-anim, top-scale;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 }


 @-webkit-keyframes plastic-bin-anim {
    from {
        bottom: 0%;
    }
    to {
        bottom: 80%;
    }
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes top-scale {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
    95% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    }
 }
```

This is an animation where I am changing the position of the object on the screen and also using scale to make it bigger and then smaller so it looks like throwing it. Basically, I am using 2 animations in the same time.

As i said, all working fine in iOS and in browser.

I am a native mobile developer for years and this is my first hybrid app, so would appreciate if someone can help me as I am out of solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this shall answer all your questions https://www.joshmorony.com/using-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Turns out the swipe detection response is really slow in Android. I am using Hammer lib, and still looking for solution to improve it.

Comment: @DejanAtanasov http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/